# find column with non-na value and create a third column filling value with the non-na column's name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, multiple-columns

For each row, I want to find which columns have `non-na` value first and remove other columns with `NaN`. Then create a third column filling with the non-na column name (modified).

```
df
ID   groupA_b1   groupA_b2   groupB_b1   groupB_b2   groupC_b1   groupC_b2
1    3           3           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2    4           5           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN 
3    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         12          1
4    NaN         NaN         8           7           NaN         NaN
```

```
Expected output
ID   b1    b2   group
1    3     3    groupA     
2    4     5    groupA    
3    12    1    groupC
4    8     7    groupB
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using `stack` after convert the columns to multiple index by `MultiIndex`

```
s=df.set_index('ID')
s.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple))
s.stack(level=0).reset_index()
Out[153]: 
   ID level_1    b1   b2
0   1  groupA   3.0  3.0
1   2  groupA   4.0  5.0
2   3  groupC  12.0  1.0
3   4  groupB   8.0  7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
df['group'] = df.set_index('ID').notnull().idxmax(1).tolist()
```

Outputs

```
ID
1    groupA_b1
2    groupA_b1
3    groupC_b1
4    groupB_b1
dtype: object
```

If you want only `A`, `C` etc:

```
df['group'].str.get(5)

0    A
1    A
2    C
3    B
Name: group, dtype: object
```